# zeroinflatedpoisson model in python

Tags: python-3.x, data-analysis, statsmodels

I want to use **python3** to build a zeroinflatedpoisson model. I found in library  `statsmodel` the function `statsmodels.discrete.count_model.ZeroInflatePoisson`.
I just wonder how to use it. It seems I should do:
 `ZIFP(Y_train,X_train).fit()`.
But when I wanted to do prediction using `X_test`.
It told me the length of `X_test` doesn't fit `X_train`. 
Or is there another package to fit this model? 
Here is the code I used:

```
X1 = [random.randint(0,1) for i in range(200)]
X2 = [random.randint(1,2) for i in range(200)]
y = np.random.poisson(lam = 2,size = 100).tolist()
for i in range(100):y.append(0)
df['x1'] = x1
df['x2'] = x2
df['y'] = y
df_x = df.iloc[:,:-1]
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(df_x,df['y'],test_size = 0.3)
clf = ZeroInflatedPoisson(endog = y_train,exog = x_train).fit()
clf.predict(x_test)

ValueError:operands could not be broadcat together with shapes (140,)(60,)
```

also tried:

```
clf.predict(x_test,exog = np.ones(len(x_test)))

ValueError: shapes(60,) and (1,) not aligned: 60 (dim 0) != 1 (dim 0)
```

Comment: Show the actual code that you tried. The model name is `ZeroInflatedPoisson` and `fit` and `predict` work in the same way as in other models in statsmodels with the addition of the options for the zero-inflation part.

Comment: train_x,test_x,train_y,test_y = train_test_split(data_x,data['y'],test_size = 0.3)
      clf = ZeroInflatedPoisson(endog = train_x, exog = train_y).fit()
      clf.predict(test_x)
      ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (140,) (60,)

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a bug to me.

As far as I can see:

If there are no explanatory variables, exog_infl, specified for the inflation model, then a array of ones is used to model a constant inflation probability.
However, if exog_infl in predict is None, then it uses the model.exog_infl which is an array of ones with the length equal to the training sample.

As work around specifying a 1-D array of ones of correct length in predict should work.

Try:

```
clf.predict(test_x, exog_infl=np.ones(len(test_x))
```

I guess the same problem will occur if exposure was used in the model, but is not explicitly specified in predict.

Comment: I tried. It shows "ValueError: shapes (60,) and (1,) not aligned: 60 (dim 0) != (dim 0)" And if I align an array for exog_infl in training. Should I change it everytime when I do prediction?

Comment: Edit your question and add the full traceback or at least the last part that shows where the shape mismatch is. Informative tracebacks are a great feature of Python.

Comment: ZeroInflated models in general expect two exog, and obviously the case if exog_infl is None is not correctly handled yet. So a workaround and full specification will be needed until this is fixed in statsmodels. (ZeroInflated is new and there are still usability bugs until there is enough feedback to fix those.)

Comment: I updated my code. I tried `clf.predict(x_test,exog_infl = len(x_test))` It works. But I don't know if that exog_infl make sense.

Comment: Any explanation about why there  ZeroInflated models in general expect two exog ?

Comment: @Mithril Zero inflated models are two part models, one model for the zero inflation and one model for the counts. The zero inflation probability can be constant, then `exog_infl` is just ones, or it can depend on other explanatory variables

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem, landing me on this thread. As noted by Josef, it seems like you need to provide exog_infl with a 1-D array of ones of correct length to work. 
However, the code Josef provided misses the 1-D array-part, so the full line required to generate the required array is actually

```
clf.predict(test_x, exog_infl=np.ones((len(test_x),1))
```